# how to remove login check when item added to wishlist?

Tags: magento-1.9, wishlist

I want to add an item in the wishlist without the customer logging in into Magento.

menace guest user can add item in wishlist. I don't want further added item, menace I send inquiry form to mail or add data in database or display at admin side. but I not want log in check when item added to wishlist.

Is it possible ? I already tried more. but no get any idea.

I see `app\code\core\Mage\Wishlist\controllers\IndexController.php`
but not getting result.

Please advice me.

Comment: If you interested in existing such feature in magento - answer NO. You need to install such module or do customization yourself.

Answer (score 2):

Wishlist module is only for register user without customer loggin,you cannot  add item at wishlist.

**Because of**`:Wishlist module architecture and tables are  save customer data in db table.If you want to this guest customer then you need lot of works at a db tables and Modules Mage_Wishlist`.

So it will be better idea to `don't use Magento defeult Wishlist for guest customer`.

Use any 3rd party module.Like:

- [magentogarden](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/63182/how-to-remove-login-check-when-item-added-to-wishlist)
- [MLX](http://www.mlx-store.com/magento2-extensions/customer-experience/guest-wishlist-for-magento-2.html)